# How to scrape every specific amount of time with Python Selenium Chrome Driver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, scrape

**Situation:** There is a website which requires me to scrape information from it every x seconds. The site in question has information which requires my input, thus I decided to go with Selenium. The action flow looks like that: User can click in the browser section or interact with the website and the Selenium browser will scrape a specific piece of information every x seconds.

**What have I tried?:**

- driver.wait (for any kind of element or a specific time); this, unfortunately, doesn't work as I don't have a specific element the browser shall wait for.
- time.sleep(0.5) in a while True loop; this didn't work as the scraping and processing part (which may run simultaneously) took time as well, this time.sleep(0.5) may be off by a few seconds.
- I looked into creating a Google Chrome Plugin which may do actions and send that information to the Python script in charge, though this surpassed the efforts it should, hence I decided against it.

**To sum up**, how can I scrape information from a Selenium Chrome Driver session every fixed amount of time?

Comment: Store the start time of the scrape, then use a while loop every 1/10(?) second and check the time difference. If the difference is more than x seconds, trigger the new scrape and reset the start time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wait for the difference between when you start and end. You also need to make sure you have a time that is greater than the time it takes your program. Used 5 here so if your program takes 1 second to run than it would wait for 5-1=4 seconds. This does get the difference in floating values so you can switch to int and do some checks for 0-1 second.

```
import time
while True:
    now = time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
    later = time.time()
    difference = (later - now)
    print(difference)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5-difference)
```